# CoreXY mesh probing issue

Tags: bed-leveling, bltouch, corexy, reprap-firmware

I am trying to compensate for bed leveling by measuring a mesh with my Z probe, a BLTouch, and I am unable to do so.

I am using RepRap firmware version 3 and have a CoreXY printer.  The first thing I do is home all axes, which works fine, and then choose `G29` (run mesh compensation). The mesh compensation then begins to lower the bed and it eventually hits the Z limit switch and keeps going and the steppers begin grinding.

Don't know how the mesh compensation works but this is my `config.g` file.  Does anyone know what may be the issue?

````
    ; Configuration file for Duet 3 (firmware version 3)
    ; executed by the firmware on start-up
    ;
    ; generated by RepRapFirmware Configuration Tool v3.2.3 on Wed Jun 23 2021 23:47:21 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
    
    ; General preferences
    G90                                             ; send absolute coordinates...
    M83                                             ; ...but relative extruder moves
    M550 P"Duet 3"                                  ; set printer name
    M669 K1                                         ; select CoreXY mode
    
    ; Drives
    M569 P0.0 S1                                    ; physical drive 0.0 goes forwards
    M569 P0.1 S1                                    ; physical drive 0.1 goes forwards
    M569 P0.2 S1                                    ; physical drive 0.2 goes forwards
    M569 P1.1 S1                                    ; physical drive 1.1 goes forwards
    M569 P1.2 S1                                    ; physical drive 1.2 goes forwards
    M584 X0.0 Y0.1 Z0.2:0.3:0.4:0.5 E1.1:1.2                    ; set drive mapping
    M350 X16 Y16 Z16 E16:16 I1                      ; configure microstepping with interpolation
    M92 X40.00 Y40.00 Z400.00 E420.00:420.00        ; set steps per mm
    M566 X900.00 Y900.00 Z60.00 E120.00:120.00      ; set maximum instantaneous speed changes (mm/min)
    M203 X6000.00 Y6000.00 Z120.00 E1200.00:1200.00 ; set maximum speeds (mm/min)
    M201 X500.00 Y500.00 Z10.00 E250.00:250.00      ; set accelerations (mm/s^2)
    M906 X1500 Y1500 Z1500 E800:800 I30             ; set motor currents (mA) and motor idle factor in per cent
    M84 S30                                         ; Set idle timeout
    
    ; Axis Limits
    M208 X0 Y0 Z0 S1                                ; set axis minima
    M208 X635 Y540 Z500 S0                          ; set axis maxima
    
    ; Endstops
    M574 X1 S1 P"!io4.in"                           ; configure active-low endstop for low end on X via pin !io1.in
    M574 Y1 S1 P"!io5.in"                           ; configure active-low endstop for low end on Y via pin !io5.in
    M574 Z2 S1 P"!io3.in"                           ; configure active-low endstop for low end on Z via pin !io3.in
    
    ; Z-Probe
    M950 S0 C"io7.out"                              ; create servo pin 0 for BLTouch
    M558 P9 C"^io7.in" H7 F120 T6000                ; set Z probe type to bltouch and the dive height + speeds
    M558 H30                                        ;*** Remove this line after delta calibration has been done and new delta parameters have been saved
    G31 P500 X0 Y0 Z2.5                             ; set Z probe trigger value, offset and trigger height
    M557 X15:215 Y15:195 S20                        ; define mesh grid
    
    ; Heaters
    M308 S0 P"temp1" Y"thermistor" T100000 B4138    ; configure sensor 0 as thermistor on pin temp1
    M950 H0 C"out1" T0                              ; create nozzle heater output on out1 and map it to sensor 0
    M307 H0 B0 S1.00                                ; disable bang-bang mode for heater  and set PWM limit
    M143 H0 S280                                    ; set temperature limit for heater 0 to 280C
    M308 S1 P"temp2" Y"thermistor" T100000 B4138    ; configure sensor 1 as thermistor on pin temp2
    M950 H1 C"out2" T1                              ; create nozzle heater output on out2 and map it to sensor 1
    M307 H1 B0 S1.00                                ; disable bang-bang mode for heater  and set PWM limit
    M143 H1 S280                                    ; set temperature limit for heater 1 to 280C
    
    ; Fans
    M950 F0 C"out7" Q500                            ; create fan 0 on pin out7 and set its frequency
    M106 P0 S1 H-1                                  ; set fan 0 value. Thermostatic control is turned off
    M950 F1 C"out8" Q500                            ; create fan 1 on pin out8 and set its frequency
    M106 P1 S1 H-1                                  ; set fan 1 value. Thermostatic control is turned off
    
    ; Tools
    M563 P0 D0 H1 F0                                ; define tool 0
    G10 P0 X0 Y0 Z0                                 ; set tool 0 axis offsets
    G10 P0 R0 S0                                    ; set initial tool 0 active and standby temperatures to 0C
    
    ; Custom settings are not defined
    
    ; Miscellaneous
    M575 P1 S1 B57600                               ; enable support for PanelDue
```
````